# Bottom Sheet not working on Kitkat(Pre-lollipop device)

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

Hi I am able to run bottom sheet on android 5.0 but not on kitkat.

***Edited*** The strange thing is that when i presee recent app and open the app again it starts working? no clue O.o
Here is my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
..}

View mBottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.location_bottom_sheet);
BottomSheetBehavior        mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(mBottomSheet);

        mBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });
```

on Click i am doing this

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                mBottomSheet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        }, 500);
```

still it is not working anyboyd have any idea why is this happening.

Comment: Are you using bottom sheet dialog or fragment? Please post code where are you showing bottom sheet.

Comment: I am using BottomSheet from support design

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with KitKat and BottomSheet from 23.0.2.
In my case it was caused by order of tags in the activity's xml.
I placed the BottomSheet before map and in this case the BottomSheet was overlapped by the map on KitKat (but was not on Android 5). So to solve the problem you should do for example:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
...

 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet>
...
```

and **not vice versa**. Hope I'm specific enough:)

Comment: THe other thing i noticed was using linearlayout instead of framge layout as root container of bottomsheet

Comment: Here I created more comprehensive example: https://plnkr.co/edit/G7luSS0DHSJKMrVDoShN In fact my real layout is very large and complex but finally BottomSheet in this exmple is overlapped by Google Map fragment. This behaviour is reproduced on pre-lolipop devices only.

Comment: did you got bottom sheet working... can you please help me over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985403/botomsheetdialog-fabbutton-anchor-view-not-working-as-expected/36986029

Answer (score 0):

This is the known issue as dicussed by google developers
On some Pre-lollipop devices bottom sheet does not work

I found a solution after R&D for a day. 
Try this

```
  ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(yourCoordinator, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(yourCoordinator);
            }
        });
```

Put this code after initializing views